# How to execute commands needed to prepare an artifact

Tags: aws-cdk

Is there a best practice for executing a preparation command within a CDK stack?

For example, if I was creating a Lambda and I wanted to run `serverless package` before deployment, is there a way to have the CDK execute that command when necessary? I was reading the documentation and it seems like *maybe* [Construct#prepare](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Construct.html#protected-prepare) would be appropriate?

Basically all I need to run is a `child_process.execSync`.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches that I would recommend:

**1. Use a wrapper script (e.g. `scripts` section of `package.json`):**

```
{
   "name": "your-app",
   "scripts":{
      "deploy": "serverless package && cdk deploy"
   }
}
```

**2. Use cdk.json**

```
{
  "app": "serverless package && npx ts-node bin/ci.ts"
}
```

Use the first if your project already uses package.json as an entrypoint for common operations. The second one is more generic but I dislike it because it's a bit more "hidden" (people who are new to CDK may never notice that it's there).